# Angular 2 class property value and binding

Tags: angular, binding

I am new to Angular 2 and I am making my first test app.

I tested class property and binding.

To check how classes work in Angular, I used many different ways, and every one works.

First, created a class on my **app.component.css**

```
.setGreenBackGroundClass
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

I created one variable on my **app.component.ts**

```
assignedVar = 'setGreenBackGroundClass';
```

I assigned the var´s name to the class and everything works right; class is assigned.

```
<ul [class]="assignedVar">
```

or

```
<ul class="{{assignedVar}}">
```

Both work fine.

Last way to test is passing directly the class name to the URL, and it works right too:

```
<ul class="setGreenBackGroundClass">
```

But my doubt comes when I tried to test binding and double binding. I wanted to create an input where I can write the value of the class property, and then, the color changes (i know, maybe it´s pretty nonsense and it would be better done with a select tag or something similar, but just wanted to check it).

On my **app.component.html** view I have:

```
<input type="text" name="miBind" [(ngModel)]="binding" />

<!--on this div I check double binding works right-->
<div>{{binding}}</div>


<ul [class]="binding">

    ....
```

The problem is at

```
<ul [class]="binding">
```

I have checked, and it works when you write on the textbox the css class name:

input--> setGreenBackGroundClass

This works. The  background color changes.

But when I do:

input-->assignedVar

It doesn´t work, and my question is: why, since assignedVar has the class name assigned, it doesn´t work?

The resulting HTML that I get from the inspector when I type "assignedVar" is:

```
<ul _ngcontent-c0="" class="setGreenBackGroundClass">
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
    <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://angular.io  /tutorial" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
        <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki" rel="noopener" target="_blank">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
        <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://blog.angular.io/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Angular blog</a></h2>
    </li>
</ul>


<ul _ngcontent-c0="" class="setGreenBackGroundClass">
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
    <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://angular.io/tutorial" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
        <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki" rel="noopener" target="_blank">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
        <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://blog.angular.io/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Angular blog</a></h2>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul _ngcontent-c0="" class="setGreenBackGroundClass">
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
    <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://angular.io/tutorial" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
        <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki" rel="noopener" target="_blank">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
        <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://blog.angular.io/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>

<input _ngcontent-c0="" name="miBind" ng-reflect-name="miBind" ng-reflect-model="assignedVar" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" type="text">

<div _ngcontent-c0="">assignedVar</div>

<ul _ngcontent-c0="" class="assignedVar">
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
        <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://angular.io/tutorial" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
        <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki" rel="noopener" target="_blank">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li _ngcontent-c0="">
        <h2 _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://blog.angular.io/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Angular blog</a></h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I can't figure out why the text on my input value is here taken as simple plain text (but not as the variable name) for the class value , and when I write that variable name directly on the code (like I did on first examples) there is no problem and it knows it is a CSS class name.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what's your question. Can you try to reproduce it [**here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-jngvft?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)?

Comment: Assuming `input-->assignedVar` means you're typing 'assignedVar' into the input, then this puts the string 'assignedVar' into variable 'binding'. It as nothing to do with the variable `assignedVar`.

Comment: @developer033     done! [**Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-v3zmyb) you have.

Answer (score 0):

> input--> setGreenBackGroundClass
>
> This works. The background color changes.
>
> But when I do:
>
> input-->assignedVar
>
> It doesn´t work.

When you input 'setGreenBackGroundClass', this is what happens

```
<ul class='setGreenBackGroundClass'>
```

which is what you expect to work.

When you input 'assignedVar', this is what happens

```
<ul class='assignedVar'>
```

and you don't have a css class with the name 'assignedVar' that's why it is not working. You confused the string `assignedVar` with the variable `assignedVar`

**Update 1**

With a stackblitz project provided, I modified your code to make your second `<ul>` to bind to a getter function.

Why I bind to a function?

Because I want to override the `binding` variable to return a `assignedVar` variable whenever you type a `assignedVar` string.

Checkout this updated [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-1?file=app/app.component.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but when I write on the code itself (with no input) `<ul [class]="assignedVar">` or `<ul class="{{assignedVar}}">` it works.

Comment: using [class] and a plain `class` with ul is different. With brackets, you are referring to the variable on your component. With plain class, you are only referring to a string

Comment: And when you are using a curly brace with just a plain `class`, you are referring to your variable. Just remember when you use a curly brace, you are always referring something on your component. You will get used to it :)

Comment: The information you provided me is very helpful, thanks! But in order to help you understand what is my problem (or actually what I don´t understand), please [**check this code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-v3zmyb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) :)